# Javascript Scheduling Display once a day Function

Tags: javascript

Hi friends I need your help on a topic, I have the topic of the sub popup ad. I want this ad to show only 1 time per day.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('popup-box').classList.remove('is-hide');
    document.body.className += " popup-flow-box"
}, 7000);

function removeClassonBody() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.className = element.className.replace(/\bpopup-flow-box\b/g, "")
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: one time per user, or one time in total across all? The former is workable, the latter involves an outside-of-the-browser location for storage.

Comment: Displayed once per user.

Comment: side note, you shouldn't really need the DATA things --- thats from an age of XHTML and HTML5 is not the same

Comment: Well then you're going to log when a user has seen it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I just want every visitor to see the ad only once a day.

Comment: Well, Utkanos has given you a clue as to how you can achieve it. keep a log of when (if at all) the ad was previously shown, and then use that to decide whether to show it again or not

Answer (score 1):

Note that the code will not run on the snippet editor in StackOverflow due to sandboxing. Copy/Paste it into a JSFiddle or similar for a working example.

Button added in to show toggling effect.

```js
const lastUseValue = localStorage.getItem('last-use');

if (!lastUseValue || (Date.now() - lastUseValue) > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
  document.body.classList.add('show-pop-up');

  localStorage.setItem('last-use', Date.now());
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  localStorage.removeItem('last-use');
})
```

```css
.pop-up {
  display: none;
}

body.show-pop-up .pop-up {
  display: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop-up">
  I'm an ad!
</div>

<button>Clear last use</button>
```

Comment: care to expand upon that?

Comment: I want to do the following user entered the site, showed ads, if the user visits tomorrow to show again tomorrow.

Comment: just shortened it down to 10 seconds to check, it definitely hides it if less than 10 seconds has elapsed. therefore, this will work with any arbitrary time gap.

Comment: @DetectiveStudio this code looks useful. If you have a problem when using it, you'll need to give a much more specific description of your difficulty. No one can fix "didn't work", that's not a useful piece of information